# Remix IDE Waring for "Required Compiler Version"

Tags: solidity, remix, compiler

I am well versed with solidity and often use Remix IDE. Quite recently, despite adding a compiler version in my code. I am still getting this warning

`Warning: Source file does not specify required compiler version! Consider adding "pragma solidity ^0.6.5;".`

The code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.5;'
Contact A{
<Something>
}
```

Any guidance, why is this happening?

Edit: It works fine in incognito mode.

Comment: I wish I knew the answer to this, it happens to me 80% of the time. Sometimes closing remix and starting fresh helps.. but this error is happening for no reason as far as i can tell. What is incognito mode?

Comment: Backup your files and remove all cookies. That should start a fresh remix. If the problem continue then it is not remix, but something in your files. Try using a fixed version `pragma solidity =0.6.5;` and select.

Answer (score 0):

hope it's not too late to answer this.

i had this issue too. apparently it was due to a failure in getting one of the dependencies (think import "";) files which resulted in a blank dependency.

when calling that import, it always turns this error.

i fixed it by removing my .deps/github folder to resync all the github dependencies (or any other dependencies you have)

hope this helps